# Send substitutions to CloudBuild from spinnaker

Tags: google-cloud-build, spinnaker

I have a Cloud Build trigger that is triggered from **Spinnaker** via **Cloud Build stage**. It can be triggered for various commit from various branch. I would like to have (at least) the branch name accessible in the cloud build pipeline but I don't see the way how to do it.

1. $BRANCH_NAME substitution variable is not set (as opposed to *automatic* cloudbuild trigger) (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values)
2. There is no way to send custom substitution variables (or is it?). From the [code](https://github.com/spinnaker/igor/blob/fb5d01e8457cadc61ecd9ed93878d7c188bf6430/igor-web/src/main/java/com/netflix/spinnaker/igor/gcb/GoogleCloudBuildClient.java#L70), it seems that it could be provided through the [RepoSource](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/cloudbuild/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/cloudbuild/v1/model/RepoSource.html)

I suppose I could get the branch from git itself, but that would need to have an unshallow copy which I don't want due to build time optimization.

Comment: I don't follow you. The problem is in Spinnaker or in Cloud Build? In both cases, how are you triggering the Cloud Build trigger? gcloud command? API call?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I point to a problem in Spinnaker (and its builtin cloud build stage). I guess it calls the cloud build API based on the code I attached. I suppose that you can send substitutions to a trigger via the API, right?

Comment: Can you share your spinnaker code that trigger Cloud Build?

Comment: Maybe a misunderstanding. This is not my code, but Spinnakers and I pinned the repo where I think it gets called (https://github.com/spinnaker/igor/blob/fb5d01e8457cadc61ecd9ed93878d7c188bf6430/igor-web/src/main/java/com/netflix/spinnaker/igor/gcb/GoogleCloudBuildClient.java#L70).

Comment: Anyway I'm able to run the trigger with correctly set BRANCH_NAME with this command: `curl -X POST https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT/triggers/$TRIGGER_ID:run \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer ...' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{
  "commitSha":"fdd361db30e60cc44730a102a9f3b026377f6775",
  "substitutions": {
    "BRANCH_NAME": "adam-test"
  }
}'` So it means that I'm just missing that option in Spinnaker. I can create a custom stage for it, just wondering if this could be supported out of the box.

Comment: I'm not so good in spinnaker. I would say that nothing exist out of the box, but A double check, or another answer could be great!

Answer (score 1):

I think the definition in Igor you're pointing at is for when it reads back the triggered events from cloudbuild itself. The requesting stage in Orca seems to take into the branch name as part of the [repo source](https://github.com/spinnaker/orca/blob/b2e18aa633f836864125c34357d2bac77ff65052/orca-igor/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/orca/igor/model/GoogleCloudBuildRepoSource.java). I'm not too familiar with the CloudBuild stage itself. But if you look into the JSON of the stage you should be able to provide the branch name via variable substitution into thhe reposource.branchName field

Comment: Thanks @TomasLin ! Sounds promising, I tried to modify the JSON, but the `branchName` is always automatically set to null when I save it on the UI. It probably corresponds to the UI itself that you can only set one of the `commitSha`, `branchName` and `tagName`. I also tried to add the cloud build substitions directly (as it works via curl too) ```"repoSource": {
    "commitSha": "${commit_hash}",
    "substitutions": {
      "BRANCH_NAME": "${branch}"
    }
  }```, but it's not propagated (as it is missing in the orca model). If the model would allow the substitutions it could work.